# Difference between a register being live-in and live-out to an instruction

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

What is the difference between a register being live-in and live-out?

My understanding is that a live-out register means that the register specified in the current line contains a variable that is not changed from its successive line.

Here is some machine code from my *Compilers* Exam that could assist with an answer

```
L0 : lim z, 0
L1 : jmp L6
L2 : sub x, x, y
L3 : mov t, z
L4 : lim z, 0
L5 : addi z, t, 1
L6 : blth y, x, L2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that for a given instruction in the program, a register is live-in if it is live before the instruction is executed and it is live-out if it is live after the instruction is executed.

To start from the beginning, a register is live at a given point in the program if its contents will be used before the register is reset. As an example, At the point between `L2` and `L3`, the register `z` is live since it will be used in the future (by `L3`) but `t` is dead since there is no use of `t` before the value is changed. This implies that `z` is live-in for `L3` and live-out for `L2` while `t` isn't.